# JDBC connection issue with RowSet

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

Hi Im wondering if anyone has experience of this, Im using netbeans and I suddenly cant connect to my mysql localhost database using rowset on the projects I have using rowset but I can using the Connection class on projects using that class.

Im getting this error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failureThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: CommunicationException doesn't have to do anything with JDBC RowSet

Comment: And for that matter, Comment all the lines exception the connection creation statements and see if you got the connection or not

Comment: Ya its something else I can get it working on one rowset project and its also a popping up on a project with a connection class

Comment: You're having trouble communicating with your database. It's not really a code problem.

Comment: Some projects are connecting fine now, still dont know whats really the issue, had to add the mysql jar/driver on one or two projects, not sure its related